# How can I get the type of a textbox in watin?

Tags: c#, testing, watin

I would like to get the type of the textbox using watin.  Do we have any methods which can do this?

Suppose if we had two text boxes with name and phone number, we can get the value of the text box by using `t.getValue();`.  There is no way to get what type of data it should contain as far as I know.  `t.getType()` returns the IE instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try `t.GetAttributeValue("type")`.

Comment: i will try and let you know, unfortunately it will always return type as text

Comment: @rockyit86: All HTML attribute values are string values, after all.